# Oracle refresh throws a table not found exception

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, refresh, materialized-views

Having simple refresh script:

```
BEGIN 
DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH(
  LIST => 'SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME', 
  PUSH_DEFERRED_RPC => TRUE, 
  REFRESH_AFTER_ERRORS => FALSE, 
  PURGE_OPTION => 1, 
  PARALLELISM => 0, 
  ATOMIC_REFRESH => TRUE, 
  NESTED => FALSE); 
END;
```

Oracle argues that:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2251
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2457
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2426
ORA-06512: at line 2
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
```

Question: what am I missing?

Note:

- Refreshed MV does exist
- if schema is not specified result is the same

Comment: have you tried wihout specifying schema? Only the materialized view_name? Can you put the ddl of MV as an update to question?

Comment: This page may be helpful: http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00942_table_or_view_does_not_exist.htm

Comment: @Frosy Z, it seems that one of the view tables has some broken dependencies. Thanx for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a common case of view, depending on some other tables or views (which might depend on other data), having broken dependencies. In this particular case the view depended on other view which depended on a table which was missing a column. Thanx to [Frosty Z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/488666/frosty-z) for giving a [hint](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00942_table_or_view_does_not_exist.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I have read elsewhere that performing a

```
ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW schema_name.table_name COMPILE;
```

can fix this issue.

it didn't work for me and i have to drop and re-create the materialized view completely.